# MS Access 365 - Create SubForm Containing Linked Files

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, subform

I've created a table and form to track sales opportunities.  I'd like users to be able to "connect"  associated files on our server to each opportunity.  For example, they might like the opportunity to point to price quote.

Since attaching files to the database is a debatable move, I've opt to save the path and would like to use `FollowHyperlink` to navigate and open the file.

My strategy is to create a subform containing the links associated with a particular opportunity. The user could then click on the subform nick name in the subform to open the associated file.

By surfing the web, I've managed to create a macro allowing the user to store the selected file and path in a column called `LinkLocation` , assign the entry a nick name via a `InputBox`, and store the nickname in a column called `LinkName`. This macro is working as expected.

Edit: Code shared.

```
Sub test()

 Dim f    As Object
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strShorthand As String ' Short hand name for display in subform.
 Dim strFullFilePath As String ' Full file path

 Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)

 f.allowMultiSelect = False
 
 f.Show
 
 strFullFilePath = f.SelectedItems(1)
 
 strShorthand = InputBox("Enter the shorthand name here.")
  
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblLinks (LinkLocation, LinkName) Values ('" & 
    strFullFilePath & "','" & strShorthand & " ');"
 
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

I am having two problems.

1. When I click to create a new record in the subform linked to `tblLinks`, my macro runs and the data is correctly stored.  However, the newly created record does not show up in the subform.
2. How do you create a double click event so `FollowHyperlink` properly engages and opens the file in question?

I cannot find an answer to either of these questions on the web.

I've written a fair amount of complex VBA for Excel, but Access is completely new to me.  Any resources you can recommend are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) refresh/requery subform, 2) same way you create any event. I don't use macros, only VBA.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this was not very helpful.

Comment: Suggestion to requery/refresh form was not helpful? Do research on Requery and Refresh commands. Your question is really too broad. There is no code for analysis.

Comment: "working code" attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter values into bound controls on form instead of running INSERT action and issue will go away. Instead of InputBox for LinkName, just enter into textbox on form. If intent is to enter a new item, make sure focus is on new record row. Then code behind subform:

```
Me.LinkLocation = strFullFilePath
```

Otherwise, have to Requery or Refresh form to display new record. Again, if code is behind subform, simply: `Me.Requery`.

As for double click event, you already know how to create VBA code so do the same for this event using FollowHyperlink command. Can be double click of a textbox or single click of command button. Format either to look like clickable hyperlink. Set textbox as locked so user cannot accidentally edit.

Comment: Thanks.  Putting the code in the bound controls is very new to me.  Once I tried this writing the VBA was easy enough.  A new issue has cropped up...the elements created in the subform (the path and the nickname) are not "saving."  A task for another day.

Comment: Data is committed to table when 1) close table/query/bound form or 2) move to another record or 3) run code to save. Bound forms and controls is a major benefit of using Access as user interface.

Comment: Data is committing to the table behind the form, but not "reappearing" when I move to the next record and then back to the original.  I don't have this issue with other subforms in the main form.  I cannot seem to set this relationship correctly.  Any tutorials you can recommend for properly setting up subforms are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything I could refer you to that would help. If you have successfully linked other form/subform setups, should be simple to do another. What are the master/child link fields? Your original INSERT action did not seem to populate a foreign key field and therefore there was no master/child link set.

Comment: Muddled my way through. I ended linking my top form primary key - OpportunityID to a "helper column" in the subform also called Opportunity ID (foreign key?) in my link table.  It feels sloppy but appears to be working.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Why would that feel sloppy? Sounds like a perfectly normal PK/FK association. Haven't you done this already with other relationships? However, advise not use spaces in naming convention nor use exact same field name in multiple tables.

Comment: Cannot put my finger on it...perhaps because I don't understand exactly how DB's connect...which I don't.  BTW, I checked my subform table..and renamed the FK field to be sure there isn't a space.  Made a quick sweep through the rest of the DB, too.  Thanks.